# Получение значения из шейдера

Tags: c++, opengl

Пусть имеется простые шейдера, образующие шейдерную программу:

**sh.vert**

```
layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;
out vec4 vertexColor;
uniform vec2 u_vector;

void main() {
    gl_Position = vec4(position, 1.0);
    vertexColor = vec4(0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
}
```

**sh.frag**

```
in vec4 vertexColor; 
out vec4 color;

void main() {
    color = vertexColor;
}
```

Подобных шейдерных программ имеется много, и каждый объект в программе может использовать свой. 
Вопрос следующий: можно ли как-то узнать, какое значение присвоено юниформ переменной `u_vector`?

Comment: Какое зададите из основной программы, такое и будет присвоено ..

Comment: Я смотрю, вы уже несколько вопросов задали, но ни на одном не отметили ответ как верный. Если ответ устраивает, тут принято жмякать на галочку слева от него. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для этого есть [`glGetUniform*`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGetUniform.xhtml), название говорит само за себя. :)

Или можно просто самому хранить копию значения uniform'а.